# I quit my Masters halfway so should I tell about that during my interview?

Tags: masters

Due to that, my resume look empty (during my post graduate study). If the interviewer ask me what I have done during that time, what should I answer?

Comment: You should tell the truth.  Always.  In the United States, and probably elsewhere, lying during the application process can be grounds for ending your employment.

Comment: Answer honestly, of course.

Comment: Have you down something else (and maybe "better" during the time)? While you should be honest, you should also present yourself in the best light.